# How to retrieve specific combination of row and column from a MySQL database?

Tags: php, sql

I have a database which has an INT column called "registries", and a  method that updates this column registries. But first I need to retrieve the data from the specific row/column combination. I was trying to do this in this way:

```
$result = mysqli_query($link,"SELECT registries FROM product WHERE name = '".$update."'");
```

Then, the new update variable is, let's say:

```
$update = $result + 5;
```

But it doesn't work. Please, can anybody help me?

Comment: RTFM: http://php.net/mysqli_query  this function returns a result handle, you have to FETCH a row of data first, extract your field from that row result, THEN you can start doing math.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mysqli_query function do not return an integer, returns an object for fetching data.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php says:

> For successful SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE or EXPLAIN queries
>   mysqli_query() will return a mysqli_result object

You have to do this:

```
$resource = mysqli_query($link,"SELECT registries FROM product WHERE name = '".$update."'");
$result = $resource->fetch_object()->registries;
$update = $result + 5;
```

Answer (score 0):

Update it with one query:

```
UPDATE products SET registries = registries + 5 WHERE name = '$update'
```